# how toggle works internally in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a recurssive tree in **Angular2** by go through some references , There i got toggle property in my template and i haven't declared any toggle property or method in used model but still its working , can some one explain how it is working.

```
<li *ngFor="let childNode of taxonomyChildList"><input 
*ngIf="childNode.hasMoreChildren"
        type="checkbox" data-md-icheck
        (click)="childNode.toggle=!childNode.toggle" />
                <a
            *ngIf="!childNode.hasMoreChildren" (click)="records()">
{{childNode.dname
                }}</a> <label *ngIf="childNode.hasMoreChildren">
{{childNode.dname}}</label>
        <app-childnodes *ngIf="childNode.toggle"
            [startingNode]="childNode.traversalPath"></app-childnodes>
</li>
```

I want to know how it is working

```
(click)="childNode.toggle=!childNode.toggle"
```

here toggle is not defined property of object or method so how its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamic language. Since you haven't defined any `toggle`property, `childNode.toggle` is initially undefined, and undefined is falsy.

Doing

```
childNode.toggle=!childNode.toggle
```

the first time adds a `toggle` property, which is equal to  `!undefined`, and since undefined is falsy, `toggle`is now true. Clicking again makes it become false.

Note that you will get a compilation error when building your app with the AOT compiler, because templates will then be compiled to TypeScript, then to JavaScript, and TypeScript will then complain that there is no `toggle` property on your nodes (unless their type is `any`). So you should definitaly declare this `toggle` property.

Also note that the current version of Angular is 5.x. You shouldn't be using Angular 2 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

At the first execution, `childNode.toggle` is undefined, and `undefined` is what JavaScript considers to be a *[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)* value.

Negating a *falsy* value evaluates to `true`.

```js
const childNode = {};

console.log(childNode.toggle); // undefined

childNode.toggle = !childNode.toggle;

console.log(childNode.toggle); // true

childNode.toggle = !childNode.toggle;

console.log(childNode.toggle); // false
```